# Search a file using combined keywords from two input files

Tags: awk, grep

I have 2 input files below and need to Search a 3rd file using all possible keywords (InputFile1.txt+InputFile2.txt) from two input files.

**InputFile1.txt:**

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

**InputFile2.txt:**

```
Orange
Blue
```

**FileTobeSearched.txt:**

```
2.2.2.2,bla,Orange
9.9.9.9,bla,bla
2.2.2.2,bla,Blue
```

**Desired output is:**

```
2.2.2.2,bla,Orange
2.2.2.2,bla,Blue
```

My attempt to loop through this is not even worth a post. please help!

*** Requested Added output:
I would like to know which keywords triggered matching line and would like to add them to beginning of each matching line output. For instance, for line matching 2.2.2.2 AND Orange, i would like matching line to start with "2.2.2.2,Orange:" and then matching line.

*** You are right: my sample file is not good.

corrected FileTobeSearched.txt:

2.2.2.2,bla,bla bla "Orange" bla bla

9.9.9.9,bla,bla

2.2.2.2,bla,bla bla bla bla "Blue"

This would now hopefully explain why i need matching keyword added to front of matching hit.

Comment: OK, you're going to have do tell us what you mean by a "match". Based on your initial sample input/output some of us have been assuming you wanted a full string match but now it looks like you want a partial match and it may be a string or it may be a regexp match (like the grep answer already assumed). ARE the matches focused on specific fields or across each line or within any field on each line? Really THINK about what you need, state whatever it is in your question, and create a sample input/output that would exhaustively test your requirements (make sure to include false match cases).

Comment: Valid points: i will come up with better sample files and question. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, 'FILENAME==ARGV[1]{a[$0]; next} 
           FILENAME==ARGV[2]{for(k in a) b[k,$0]; next} 
           ($1,$3) in b' InputFile1.txt InputFile2.txt FileTobeSearched.txt

2.2.2.2,bla,Orange
2.2.2.2,bla,Blue
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, i made following edits and could not get it to work. what am i doing wrong:                                                               awk -F, 'InputFile1.txt==ARGV[1]{a[$0]; next} 
           InputFile2.txt==ARGV[2]{for(k in a) b[k,$0]; next} 
           ($1,$3) in b' FileTobeSearched.txt{1..3}

Comment: don't do that just run the script as is with your filenames in order instead of `file{1..3}`  OK I did it for you, see the update

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for ARGIND:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    ARGIND==1 { a[$0]; next } 
    ARGIND==2 { b[$0]; next } 
    ($1 in a) && ($3 in b) { print $1, $3 ":" $0 }
' InputFile1.txt InputFile2.txt FileTobeSearched.txt
```

With other awks change `ARGIND==1` to `FILENAME==ARGV[1]` etc. or add an initial line that says `FNR==1{ARGIND++}` if your files can't be empty.

The differences between the above and [@karakfa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42723349/1745001) are in performance:

1. his will loop through every line of file 1 once for every line of
   file 2 while mine just doesn't do that, and
2. his requires 1 string concatenation plus 1 hash lookup for every
   line of file 3 while mine doesn't require the string concatenation
   but does require 2 hash lookups (but on much smaller arrays) for every line of file 3.

Comment: Thanks, quick question: how would we add matching keywords to beginning of each matching line such as: 2.2.2.2,Orange: 2.2.2.2,bla,Orange

Comment: `^1` Naturally this is faster than what karakfa provided, could have accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use grep:

```
grep -f <(cat file1 file2) filetobesearched
```

Comment: I like this answer but it has some false positive because it seems to apply "Or" logic instead of desired "AND" logic to search keywords. any ideas on how to fix that?